# How to consume filesystem audit information

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008-r2, audit

We have a system used by some departments in the company and we were facing issues due to some miss-configurations on that system so I enabled auditing files being Written or deleted.

Now that I have this information how can I use it? Is there any tool? All I need to do with this information is to list users that modified a given file and modification dates.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question (at least in a very basic way):

```
$server = "localhost"
$out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 
$out.AppendLine("ServerName,EventID,TimeCreated,UserName,File_or_Folder,AccessMask")
$ns = @{e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"} 
$evts = Get-WinEvent -computer $server -FilterHashtable @{logname="security";id="4663"} -oldest

foreach($evt in $evts) 
{ 
    [xml]$xml = $evt.ToXml()

    $SubjectUserName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    $ObjectName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='ObjectName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    $AccessMask = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='AccessMask']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    $out.AppendLine("$($server),$($evt.id),$($evt.TimeCreated),$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask")

    Write-Host $server 
    Write-Host $evt.id,$evt.TimeCreated,$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask
} 

$out.ToString() | out-file -filepath C:\Temp\4663Events.csv
```